# How in Slick map scala objects to a column and use objects in queries

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'd like to use my custom objects as values in slick queries, similar to Scala Enumeration.

```
sealed trait UserStatus
object UserStatus {
  object Active extends UserStatus
  object Deleted extends UserStatus
}
```

I've defined MappedColumnType for UserStatus and it works fine.

```
implicit val UserStatusColumn = MappedColumnType.base[UserStatus, String](_.toString, _ => UserStatus.Active)
```

Until I want' to use these objects in queries.

```
for {
  u <- slickUsers
  if u.status === UserStatus.Active
} yield u
```

I get error

```
Error:(26, 34) type mismatch;
 found   : models.UserStatus.Active.type
 required: slick.lifted.Rep[?]
      if u.status === UserStatus.Active
```

It works fine when I explicitly say it's a UserType:

```
for (u <- slickUsers if u.status === UserStatus.Active.asInstanceOf[UserStatus]) yield u
```

Somehow I need to hint Slick that Active.type is a UserStatus type. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to help the compiler out here, and a type annotation is one easy way to do that:

```
for {
  u <- slickUsers
  if u.status === (UserStatus.Active : UserStatus)
} yield u
```

Another trick some use is to create a set of "smart constructors":

```
object UserStatus {
  object Active extends UserStatus
  object Deleted extends UserStatus 
  val active: UserStatus = Active
  val deleted: USerStatus = Deleted
}
```

...which allows you to write:

```
 for {
   u <- slickUsers
   if u.status === UserStatus.active
 } yield u
```

Comment: Well, that's similar to what I've done eventually, but I can't say it's a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
case class Task(id: Long, color: String, status: TaskStatus.Value, project: Long)

object TaskStatus extends Enumeration {
  val ready = Value("ready")
  val set = Value("set")
  val go = Value("go")
}

class TaskRepo @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) {
  val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
  import dbConfig.driver.api._
  private val Tasks = TableQuery[TasksTable]

  def findByReadyStatus: DBIO[List[Task]] =
    Tasks.filter(_.status === TaskStatus.ready).to[List].result

  private class TasksTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Task](tag, "TASK") {

    def id = column[Long]("ID", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
    def color = column[String]("COLOR")
    def status = column[TaskStatus.Value]("STATUS")
    def project = column[Long]("PROJECT")

    def * = (id, color, status, project) <> (Task.tupled, Task.unapply _)
    def ? = (id.?, color.?, status.?, project.?).shaped.<>({ r => import r._; _1.map(_ => Task.tupled((_1.get, _2.get, _3.get, _4.get))) }, (_: Any) => throw new Exception("Inserting into ? Taskion not supported."))
  }

  implicit val taskStatusColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[TaskStatus.Value, String](
    _.toString, string => TaskStatus.withName(string))

}
```

You can find the live version here: https://github.com/nemoo/play-slick3-example/blob/master/app/models/Task.scala

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using Scala Enumeration, hence I don't have values in my enum-like objects.